# Math Question : bacteria's population

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Imagine a community of bacteria living on a Petri dish. A single bacterium was placed on the dish at midnight. Their population doubled once an hour. At 1:00 a.m. there were 2 bacteria, by 2:00 a.m. there were 4 bacteria, and so forth. At noon, 12 hours later, their food supply ran out. At what time of day was half their food used up?

Comment: I think you mean to post this question on the mathematics stack exchange.  This is the Mathematica stack exchange, which is for discussing the software by Wolfram.  But, to answer your question, I believe the food is half used up at 11:am.

Answer (score 0):

Evanb is very close, but not quite correct. If the question asked for when the population is half the total, it would indeed be at 11 am. But the question is about food, not population.

However, the exact answer depends on how the population growth is modeled. Below, I assume that all bacteria divide after exactly 1 hour of eating, and the first bacterium takes a full hour in the Petri dish to reach it's division. I also assume (assuredly falsely) that even in the end the food is evenly distributed - no bacterium runs out of food until they all do.

Call the amount of food a single bacterium will eat in 1 hour a "bh". After 1 hour, the single starting bacterium will eat  $1 = 2^0$ bh. The 2nd hour, the 2 bacteria will eat an additional $2 = 2^1$ bh, $4 = 2^2$ bh will be eaten the 3rd hour, and so on. At the end of the 12th hour, a total of $$2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^{11} = 2^{12} - 1 = 4095$$
bh of food will be eaten. Since the food runs out then, there was $4095$ bh to begin with, and we want to find out when there is exactly $2047.5$ bh left. At the beginning of the 11th hour, the amount of food eaten is $2^{11}- 1 = 2047$ bh, which means there is $2048$ bh remaining. So how long does it take for that additional $0.5$ bh to be eaten? There are $2^{11} = 2048$ bacteria at this time, eating at a rate of $2048$ bh per hour, so it will take them a total $\frac {0.5}{2048} = \frac 1{4096}$ hours $\approx 1.76$ seconds to reach the halfway point.

So the correct answer (given the modeling assumptions) is not $11\colon00\colon00 $ am, but $11\colon00\colon01.76$ am.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the population growth is continuous, then the population at time $t$ is given by $p(t)=2^t$.  If one bacterium consumes food at a rate $r$ (kilocalories per hour, say) then the total food supply, $s$, is the amount of food consumed in 12 hours, or
$$s = \int_0^{12} r \, p(t) dt = r\int_0^{12} 2^t dt = \frac{4095 \, r}{\ln 2} \;.$$

The amount, $a$, consumed in 11 hours is
$$a = \int_0^{11} r \, p(t) dt = r\int_0^{11} 2^t dt = \frac{2047 \, r}{\ln 2} \;,$$
which is almost exactly 1/2 of the total supply.  Exactly half would be 2047.5 out of 4095, so 11 hours is within an accuracy of about 1 part in 4000.  A second is 1/3600 of an hour, so 11 hours has an accuracy of, roughly, one second.